# Is the pre-flight COVID test really strict on time?

Tags: covid-19, lufthansa, munich, yul, opo

Flying out of Porto Saturday at 11am to YUL via Munich on Lufthansa

The email I received says the antigen test:

Negative antigen test taken **within 1 day before departure**.

Can I take a test at around 9am Friday morning? Does that count as « within 1 day » ?

Thanks

Comment: Starting April 1, 2022, pre-entry tests will no longer be required for fully vaccinated travellers entering Canada by land, air or water. Until then, follow the pre-entry test requirements. You must still use ArriveCAN before and after April 1. https://travel.gc.ca/travel-covid/travel-restrictions/flying-canada-checklist/covid-19-testing-travellers-coming-into-canada

Comment: https://www.auswaertiges-amt.de/en/visa-service/EinreiseUndAufenthalt only speaks hours. I've _never_ seen any airlines or foreign offices talk of days re covid. There must be some mistake.

Comment: @chx US talk of days re covid.

Comment: Confusion and incompetence at check in seems to increase. Two weeks ago we flew a similar itinerary: LIS->FRA->BOS. The check in agent had to make 4 different phone calls to figure out our requirements and still got it wrong. Since the wrong version worked for us as well, I decided not to argue. He then refused to accept our (perfectly valid) tests but didn't really articulate why. After a lot of back and forth it turned out he had today's date wrong in his head. Conclusion: you can't rely on the agent to get it right, to it's good to have links to the rules with you.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

According to [the Canadian government's covid-19 testing for travelers page](https://travel.gc.ca/travel-covid/travel-restrictions/flying-canada-checklist/covid-19-testing-travellers-coming-into-canada), for a professionally administered or observed negative antigen test,

> - the one day window does not depend on the time of day the test was taken or the time of your flight or entry
> - for example, if your flight is scheduled to leave or you enter by land any time on Friday, you could provide proof of a negative result from an antigen test taken any time on Thursday, or on Friday
> - it must be administered or observed by a pharmacy, laboratory, healthcare entity or telehealth service
> - the test must be authorized for sale or distribution in Canada or in the jurisdiction in which it was obtained
> - the test must be performed outside of Canada

so a test administered Friday morning is acceptable for a flight anytime on Saturday.

Note, however, that the requirements are changing, and starting April 1, fully vaccinated travelers will no longer be required to provide proof of a negative test.

Comment: Emphasize the last part: effective tomorrow, no testing required for fully vaccinated travellers. So should not be required for @Max on Saturday April 2.

Comment: I'm transiting in Munich, so I need to get tests (according the the Lufthansa email I got). It now says the delay is 48 hours for an Antigen test.

Comment: @Max this is important: Canada and Germany might have different requirements and given you must first take a flight to Germany, you must satisfy their requirements as well.

Comment: Everything went well, they only checked my locator form in Munich (not my negative test)

Answer (score 3):

> Is the pre-flight COVID test really strict on time?

To add a more general answer in addition to mlc's answer focusing on Canada, assuming that the covid test is required for your case, that depends on the destination country's policies, the airline's policy and the transit countries' policies. In some situations, the covid test time will matter.

Comment: This. The OP's question can be answered for Canada at the present time, but the answer for _any other traveler, with any other recent travel or vaccination history, going to any other country, including a country of transit, at any other time_ could be completely different. Given the past few years' history, it will be.

Answer (score 3):

I received an email from Lufthansa with this :

"Passengers on flights to Germany must present a negative Covid-19 test upon entry into Germany. **The test must have been carried out at the earliest 48 hours (antigen) prior to arrival in Germany**, "

So it answered my concerns.

Still not sure if I stay air-side at the airport it's considered entering Germany.

I took my test earlier today and got a negative result.

So, no biggie on that front.

Comment: Transit in Germany requires either a negative test or a vaccination certificate.

Comment: Yeah, that's the OR I wasn't sure about.